# finding tag name when doing git checkout -f

Tags: git, jenkins

Is there a way to find out the git tag information when the repository is checked out with `git checkout -f <hash>` ?

I know `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` shows git tag number but in my Jenkinsfile the checkout is being done by `git checkout -f <hash>`. So the output of `git describe` from my jenkinsfile just shows the commit number but doesn't show the tag name. Is it possible to get the tag name? I've tried `env.TAG_NAME` which is empty.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: first, see if upgrading Jenkins works.  If not, try `git tag --points-at HEAD`.

There are two ways to look at this question.

- One assumes that you are trying to "go backwards", i.e., take a repository that, you discover, is in detached `HEAD` mode and guess how it got there.  The first problem is that it may not have gotten there via `git checkout <tag-name>` at all.  The second is that even if it did—in which case, `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` will show one—the one that `git describe` shows might not be the one that was actually used to accomplish the checkout.

  The reason for this is that Git's tags are primarily mechanisms for converting from human-readable names to hash IDs.  There may be *multiple names* for any one given commit hash ID, and if so, `git describe` will just pick one and use that.  In [Git versions 1.7.10 and later](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ecbdaf0899161c067986e9d9d564586d4b045d62/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.10.txt#L128-L129), `git tag --points-at HEAD` will list *all* tags that point to the current commit; you can then attempt to guess which of these, if any, was used.

  Alternatively, you can use the repository's `HEAD` reflog, which will have a line in it that contains the name of the tag, if a tag was used.  The `git status` command, in modern Git, does this, and prints `HEAD detached at tag-name` for this case.  That's more reliable than `git describe` output, *provided* the repository in question has reflogs enabled and there is a reflog entry.  Neither of these two—that reflogs are enabled, and if so, that there is a suitable entry—is guaranteed.  The describe and points-at methods are therefore more reliable.
- The other way to look at this assumes that you wish to "go forward": that Jenkins itself has done the `git checkout` operation.  In this case, all you need to do is convince Jenkins to produce for you the tag name it passed to `git checkout`.

  There *should* be a way to do this.  Really, it *should* be what you've already tried, i.e., using `env.TAG_NAME`.  This is, apparently, [claimed to work now](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46207).  Perhaps upgrading Jenkins will do the trick.

  I'd be happy to be corrected in my claim that Jenkins documentation <s>sucks big time</s> is terribly inadequate by finding some complete, comprehensive, and accurate documentation on it, that includes which versions of Jenkins support which features, what pipeline stages are run in parallel and what are not, and so forth, but I've never found any.  (Git is at least a *little* better in that one can search through the [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes) to find out when particular features were added, but here, too, things could be much better.  Compare with the Python documentation, which tries to call out when, specifically, some feature, such as [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), was new.)